After installing 24.04.1 LTS on my desktop computer, the date command displays UTC time instead of the expected local time
Recently upgraded to 24.04.1 LTS and now the date command always produces UTC time instead of using the time for the local CDT time zone.
$ timedatectl
                Local time: Sun 2024-09-29 14:14:24 CDT
            Universal time: Sun 2024-09-29 19:14:24 UTC
                    RTC time: Sun 2024-09-29 19:14:24
                Time zone: America/Chicago (CDT, -0500)
System clock synchronized: yes
                NTP service: active
            RTC in local TZ: no

Even though the local time zone is correct, the date command displays UTC time instead of CDT time:
$ date
Sun Sep 29 07:15:00 PM  2024

The timestamp displayed when ls -l is used also displays UTC time.
$ touch x
$ ls -l x
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tmacd tmacd 0 Sep 29 19:22 x

$ ls -l /etc/localtime
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Sep 23 19:39 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Chicago

Any ideas on how to force the date command to display the time by using the local time zone?

What's the output of type date? Does echo $TZ output something? TZ=America/Chicago date would probably work, but that's rather a workaround.

$ type date
date is hashed (/usr/bin/date)
$ echo $TZ
US/Central

Does TZ=America/Chicago date show the correct time?

Yes that shows the correct date.  Also TZ=America/Chicago touch x behaves as expected.

Well US/Central appears to be a correct timezone identifier, but at the same time it seems like it's messing with date, which falls back to displaying UTC instead? The obvious workaround is to put TZ=America/Chicago at the end of ~/.bashrc, however I suspect something is setting $TZ to US/Central, perhaps in ~/.bashrc or in one of the other usual suspects.

That did it.  $TZ was set in ~/.bashrc - not sure how that made its way in there.  Thanks - much appreciated.  All is well now.

I'm glad you figured it out!

TZ containing an unrecognized timezone identifier could cause date to fall back to printing UTC times.
% timedatectl
               Local time: Mon 2024-09-30 05:11:37 CEST
           Universal time: Mon 2024-09-30 03:11:37 UTC
                 RTC time: Mon 2024-09-30 03:11:37
                Time zone: Europe/Rome (CEST, +0200)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no
% date
Mon Sep 30 05:11:42 CEST 2024
% TZ=foo date
Mon Sep 30 03:11:49 foo 2024

In your case TZ was set to US/Central, which is a correct alias for America/Chicago; as muru points out in the comments, the tzfile for US/Central (or rather the symlink from US/Central to America/Chicago) is since 23.10 provided by the new package tzdata-legacy instead of tzdata istelf.
This package has likely not been installed as part of the upgrade process, while tzdata has been upgraded, and referencing US/Central (previously fine) has started to break things. This is documented in the /usr/share/doc/tzdata/NEWS.Debian.gz file as follows:
From 2023c-8 on the tzdata package ships only timezones that follow the
current rules of geographical region (continent or ocean) and city name.
All legacy timezone symlinks (old or merged timezones mentioned in the
upstream backward file) were moved to tzdata-legacy. This includes the
US/* timezones.

Please install tzdata-legacy in case you need the legacy timezones or to
restore the previous behavior. This might be needed in case the system
provides timezone-aware data over the network (e. g. SQL databases).

The solution is to trace back where TZ is being set (in your case it was being set in ~/.bashrc) and either remove TZ's definition altogether or set it to America/Chicago, or install tzdata-legacy if it is used by something you cannot change.
On my Ubuntu box TZ is unset by default, so I guess removing TZ's definition would be fine.

Looking at the package index, it looks like US/Central is in the tzdata-legacy package now, so maybe this is an optional package that's not installed by default and needs to be explicitly installed.

@muru That's a good find, I installed it and things started working. I'm still kinda scratching my head at date previously printing an empty string though, it somehow seems to be aware of US/Central despite the lack of a symlink in /usr/share/zoneinfo. I'll incorporate the tzdata-legacy thing later

Does your /usr/share/zoneinfo/tzdata.zi file mention it? My Arch box has this line: L America/Chicago US/Central

@muru Yes it does, now everything makes sense. Thanks

@muru Thanks for the edit and the info. I need some coffee, obviously the package couldn't have been removed if it's a new package :| however that makes me wonder why the new package isn't being installed by default. It's just a few symlinks, and missing those definitions could cause breakages.

Probably nobody on the Ubuntu side noticed, and users on the Debian side are expected to check the news anyway.
